# Angular2 unit testing a switchMap

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

Simple question:

I've followed the tutorial: [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html) where I have the following code:

```
this.term.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(term => this.wikipediaService.search(term));
```

Where term is a  [Control](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Control-class.html) inheriting from [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AbstractControl-class.html), how can I trigger the valueChanges observable property, so that I can perform unit tests?

Comment: I am struggling with this exact issue right now. I can get things to work if I remove the debounceTime() call, but with it I always get an error from zone.js saying I have a periodic timer still in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

I think I was experiencing the same issue.
I was trying to test that heroService.searchHeroes was called:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes$ = this.searchTerms
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap((term: string) => this.heroService.searchHeroes(term))
      );
  }
```

I was able to fix it by only calling  `tick(500)` once

```
  it('should call HeroService.searchHeroes', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(heroService, 'searchHeroes').and.returnValue(component.heroes$);
    let searchField: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#search-box'));
    searchField.nativeElement.value = 'i';
    searchField.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup'));
    tick(500);
    expect(heroService.searchHeroes).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around in the following issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8251

Essentially there's buggy behavior, but you can get a basic test working with code like this:

```
it("filter input changed should update filter string",

    fakeAsync(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
        let fixture = tcb.createFakeAsync(MyComponent);
        let component = fixture.componentInstance as MyComponent;

        fixture.detectChanges();

        // Trigger a new value to emit on the valueChanges observable
        //
        component.filter.updateValue("testing");

        // There's buggy behavior with multiple async events so we 
        //  need to run tick() twice to get our desired behavior
        //  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8251
        //
        tick();
        tick(500);

        // Now we can inspect the results of the subscription in the 
        //  original component
        //
        expect(component.filterString).toBe("testing");
    })));
```

...and this is with a component that looks like this:

```
export class MyComponent {

    filter = new Control();

    /** The current filter string */
    filterString: string;

    constructor() {
        // Subscribe to changes in the filter string
        //
        this.filter.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(200)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe((filterString: string) => {
                this.filterString = filterString;
            });

    }
}
```